# Query last week data groupBy dayOfWeek in Laravel 7

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I ran this query

```
$data = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subWeek())->get()->pluck('created_at');
dd($data);
```

I got this

```
    Illuminate\Support\Collection {#521 ▼
    #items: array:72 [▶]
    }
```

I have `72` visitors in the last 7 days.

```
Note
----

KEY : 0-6 day of week, sunday(0) & saturday(6)
VALUE : visitor count of that day
```

---

## Goal

How do I modify my query to get something like this JSON ?

```
    {
        "0":10,
        "1":10,
        "2":10,
        "3":10,
        "4":10,
        "5":10,
        "6":12
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of an item from the array?

Comment: @sta I'm not sure what is the best way to get this working in a clean optimized way possible

Comment: what are columns in Visitor table? and you should show us converted your items to an array with `dd($data->toArray())`;

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur : I updated the post with all columns of my visitor table;

Answer (score 1):

You need to `count` query with `Group By` day of week below:

```
$data = Visitor::selectRaw('DAYOFWEEK(created_at) as day,count(id) as visitors')
    ->where('created_at', ">", DB::raw('NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK'))->groupBy('day')->get();
```

If you want to convert to json like on your question just map it or simply use foreach like below:

```
$json = [];
foreach ($data as $item)
{
  $json[$item->day - 1] = $item->visitors; //use - 1 because  DAYOFWEEK from mysql start from 1 instead of 0.
}

$json = json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); // JSON_FORCE_OBJECT to avoid array result
```